# Writing a factor to a list of dataframes (factor is the name of the dataframe)

Tags: r

I have `list1` of dataframes, which i want to `do.call("rbind", list1)`later, but first i want to add a identifying factor to each of the dataframes. This factor should be the name of the dataframe:

```
    list1 <- lapply(vector("list", 6), function(x) 
                    data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:1,1000,rep=TRUE))))
    names(list1) <- LETTERS[1:6]
```

e.g. assign "A" to each row of the first dataframe "A" and so on:

```
list[[1]]$Cat <- "A"
list[[2]]$Cat <- "B" #etc
```

I tried something like

```
list1 <- lapply(list1, function(x)
                       {list1[[x]]$Cat<- names(list1[[x]]); x})
```

but failed:

```
Error in list1[[x]] : invalid subscript type 'list'
```

How to achieve what i want?
Thank you.

Comment: Do you need to do this in base R? Because both **dplyr** and **data.table** will do this for you.

Comment: Anything is fine. Thank you!

Comment: In that case, see my comment on one of the answers: `dplyr::bind_rows(list1,.id = "Cat")` is all you need. There is an equivalent functionality in **data.table** if you prefer that.

Comment: Or you can pull the info out of the row.names after the `rbind`. `myDat <- do.call(rbind, list1); myDat$cat <- sub("\\.*$", "", row.names(myDat))` should give you what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done easily using `tidyverse` packages:

```
library( tidyverse )
imap( list1, ~mutate(.x, Cat = .y) ) %>% bind_rows
```

To break this down:

1. `imap` from `purrr` package passes every element of the first argument (`list1` in this case) along with the element's name to the function you provide in the second argument. By `imap`'s convention, the function can refer to the element using `.x` and to the element's name using `.y`.
2. The function in the second argument uses `mutate` from `dplyr` package, which creates a new column named `Cat`.
3. Lastly, `bind_rows` is the tidyverse equivalent of `do.call( "rbind", list1 )` that you provided in your question.

EDIT: As joran pointed out in the comments, if your end goal is to concatenate all the data.frames together, `bind_rows` provides a convenient way to automatically prepend a column identifying the original data.frame:

```
bind_rows( list1, .id = "Cat" )
```

Comment: If you're going to use `bind_rows()`, why not just use the `.id` argument to create labels based on the list names automatically? It's just `bind_rows(list1,.id = "Cat")`.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I forgot about the `.id` argument. Answer modified to include your suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: This is what i want!